# How to split long tables across multiple slides in ppt using apache POI

Tags: java, split, apache-poi, powerpoint

I am trying to export tables to PPT using POI. But my tables can contain n number of rows.

The problem is that the entire table is displayed in the same slide. I want to split the table across slides depending on the number of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be missing something, but what's wrong with the obvious?

```
 Slide slide = hslf.createSlide();
 int rows = 0;
 int maxRowsPerSlide = 10; // Tune this

 for(MyRowThingy row : getMeMyRows()) {
     doAddRowToSlide(row, slide);

     rows++;
     if(rows % maxRowsPerSlide == 0) {
        // Slide is full, time for a new slide!
        slide = hslf.createSlide();
     }
 }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66385261/apache-poi-slide-tablexslftable-height-calculation
Any view on this question?

Answer (score 0):

in the above code i faced a problem where the last slides will contain extra columns. so the maxRowsPerSlide must be dynamic.for tht i used folowing function

```
public int getMaxRowsInOneSlide(int sizeOfTotalRowsArray, int totalCount){   //totalCount is the count of current row
    int maxRowsPerSlide = 0;

    if(sizeOfArray - totalCount >= 10){  //10 is the default rows in a slide
        maxRowsPerSlide = 10;
    }
    else{
        maxRowsPerSlide = (sizeOfArray - totalCount)+1;              //'+1' because each slide contains a row for the column names in the table
    }
    return maxRowsPerSlide;
}
}
```